# Trigger button:active style using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web application where the user will trigger interactions either by clicking on a button or using a keyboard shortcut.

The buttons give visual feedback when clicked by changing background color using:

```
button:active {
  background-color: #73B4E4;
}
```

But how do I trigger the same button feedback if the user triggers the interaction using the keyboard shortcut instead?

Some code:

Declaring the button:

```
const skipButton = document.getElementById("skip");
```

Function triggered by clicking:

```
if (skipButton) skipButton.onclick = (event) => onSkip();
```

Same function, but triggered using the keyboard shortcut:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
//commented out the other cases
    case 88:
      onSkip();
      break;
  }
};
```

I've considered looking into something like this:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

But I don't want my button to keep its active state, I just want it to flash as it is pressed (which the button:active does).

Any tips?

Comment: `.addClass()` and then `.removeClass()` after a given timeout, using `setTimeout()`.  You can't trigger a CSS pseudo class any way other than the way it was made for.

Comment: Oh, ok! I tried the following:
`case 88:
      onSkip();
      $(skipButton).addClass("active");
      break;`

But for some reason the button does not get receive the 'active' class...

This is what my HTML looks like:
`<div class="toolbar-item" id="skip">
        <button class="skip">
            <img class="icon" src="../images/skip.png" alt="">
            <p class="icon-label">Skip</p>
        </button>
      </div>`